# Difference between dexing and deploying?

Tags: android, maven

Could someone tell me the difference between dexing and deployment in android development?

Answer (score 0):

If simple:

[Dexing](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html) - is a part of app building.

Deployment - is an process of installing app to device or loading artifacts on repository.